# Android CursorLoaded with custom BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursoradapter

I have been searching for how to do this, but am coming up pretty short in my findings.

I have implemented a ContentProvider in my application.  And my fragments are using the CursorLoader call backs to query the ContentProvider.

The SimpleCursorAdapter is typically being used to used to render the results, however, I want to create a custom base adapter so that I can modify these results with section headers as they are displayed.

My overall question, is how do I pass the results of the cursor into a custom BaseAdapter?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i would do is create a CustomCursorAdapter extending from CursorAdapter.

here is an example that you can use :)

```
public class ContactListCustomCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

private static final String TAG = ContactListCustomCursorAdapter.class.getName();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;

public ContactListCustomCursorAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, null, false);
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

In the constructor you can grab the layoutInflater for inflate each view later.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    contactName = cursor.getString(cursor
            .getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
    currentId = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts._ID));
    currentChar = contactName.substring(0, 1);
    ViewHolder mHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

    if (cursor.isFirst()) {
        mHolder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mHolder.charHeader.setText(currentChar);
        mHolder.fistContactBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mHolder.normalBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        cursor.moveToPrevious();
        previousChar = cursor.getString(
                cursor.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)).substring(0,
                1);
        if (collator.compare(currentChar, previousChar) != 0) {
            mHolder.header.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mHolder.charHeader.setText(currentChar);
            mHolder.fistContactBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mHolder.normalBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            mHolder.header.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHolder.fistContactBackground.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mHolder.normalBackground.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
```

On bind view i made this to know if a row has a difference with it previous name and if the case show a separator header.

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
}
```

On getItem you can return an object or what is needed for an outside operation, like a clic on a list element.

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.contact_row, parent, false);
    ViewHolder refHolder = new ViewHolder();
    refHolder.name = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.contact_row_name_textView);
    refHolder.setContactPhoto((ImageView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.contact_row_photo_ImageView));
    refHolder.header = (LinearLayout) view
            .findViewById(R.id.contact_row_separator);
    refHolder.charHeader = (TextView) view
            .findViewById(R.id.contact_separator_char_textview);
    refHolder.normalBackground = view.findViewById(R.id.normal_background);
    refHolder.fistContactBackground = view
            .findViewById(R.id.first_contact_background);
    view.setTag(refHolder);
    return view;
}

public static class ViewHolder implements ViewHolderInterface {
    private LinearLayout header;
    private TextView name;
    private ImageView contactPhoto;
    private TextView charHeader;
    private View normalBackground;
    private View fistContactBackground; 
}
```

The viewHolder is to speedUp the view search, and on newView you set the components and store them in the Tag Object.

On your activity or fragment just have to set the cursor when its loaded.

```
    @Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> arg0, Cursor currentCursor) {
    contactsAdapter.changeCursor(currentCursor);
}
```

Now you can filter or whatever you want and the cursor will be handled by the loader :)

Regards.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at what you have posted.  From what I can tell, however, you construct the new CursorAdapter with a null cursor.  How is the reference made to the cursor that exists in the fragment?  Is it assumed through the context?

Comment: Nevermind, i missed the section above in onLoadFinished().  I think that is the piece I was missing.

Comment: This is working great, but I think there might be an issue.  My counts per section seem to be off by 2.  Just an FYI.  I am going to look into it a little deeper

Comment: What do you mean by count section? could you explain it further? :)

Comment: What I am seeing is when a new section header gets displayed, the last row in the previous section is never displayed because only the header is displayed.

Comment: i am working through it, but wanted to give you an FYI in case you are  not seeing certain rows in your final output as well

Comment: here is the actual code I am working on [link](https://github.com/MythTV-Android/mythtv-for-android/blob/master/src/org/mythtv/client/ui/dvr/UpcomingFragment.java)

Comment: can you give me the complete solution i am looking for the solution. i need to start from the beginning. please help me i need to implement this

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Adapter that extends BaseAdapter. Then in your adapter declare a field `private Cursor c` and pass your cursor to this adapter through class constructor. In your adapter implements necessary methods and that's all. [Here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/), for instance, you can read how to implement custom BaseAdapter. Moreover, you can have a look at the implementation of SimpleCursorAdapter in AOSP.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at the SimpleCursorAdapter source.